# How to prevent a link's alt text from disappearing

Tags: html, hyperlink

Is it possible to prevent the text popup that happens when you mouseover a link from disappearing after a certain amount of time. I don't wish to create a completely different text popup solution and would only like to have to pass another attribute into the anchor tag or find out if this is browser controlled.

Comment: Note that technically, you should be using the `title` attribute for the popup text, not the `alt` attribute...

Comment: Good point, "alt" won't show as a tooltip in Firefox.

Comment: Note even browsers are inconsistent with title attributes - some display newlines, and some don't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately this is controlled by the browser and can't be changed.  You could look at using something like the [jQuery Tooltip Plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-tooltip/) instead, or jQuery Tools which has a nice example of [imitating browsers default tooltip](http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/tooltip/imitate.html).

Answer (score 3):

Nope, this is entirely browser controlled and ranges from browser to browser. The only way to circumvent this would be enlarging the area of the link using padding or a similar technique, thus delaying the "mouseout" event, but this is almost always impractical in a real world layout.

You would have to use an entirely custom solution to control the timeout.